# Can I simplify this recursive concat function using List.fold_left?

Tags: ocaml

I have created a working solution for concat, but I feel that I can reduce this using List.fold_lift.

Here is my current code:

```
let rec concat (lists : 'a list list) : 'a list =
    match lists with
    | [] -> []
    | hd :: tl -> hd @ concat tl ;;
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
let concat (lists : 'a list list) : 'a list =
    List.fold_left @ lists ;;
```

This gives me the error: This expression has type 'a list list but an expression was expected of type
'a list

I think this is because the return value of list.fold_left gives us a list, but we are feeding it a list of lists so it then returns a list of lists again. How can I get around this without matching?

I was also playing around with List.map but with no luck so far:

```
let concat (lists : 'a list list) : 'a list =
    List.map (fun x -> List.fold_left @ x) lists ;;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the type signature of `List.fold_left`:

```
('a -> 'b -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'b list -> 'a
```

`List.fold_left` takes *three* arguments.

1. A function.
2. An initial value.
3. A `list` to iterate over.

```
List.fold_left @ lists
```

You're making two mistakes.

First off, this parses as `(List.fold_left) @ (lists)`.

You're looking for `List.fold_left (@) lists`. But that's still not quite right, because...

You're only passing *two* arguments, with `lists` being the initial value, while `List.fold_left` expects three.

I think that you're looking for something like:

```
let concat lists = List.fold_left (@) [] lists
```

Demonstrated:

```
# let concat lists = List.fold_left (@) [] lists in
  concat [[1;2;3]; [4;5;6]; [7;8;9]];;
- : int list = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9]
```

### Runtime complexity

The danger to this approach to concatenating lists is that while it runs in constant stack space since `List.fold_left` is tail-recursive and `@` is (at least as of this edit), it's runtime complexity is O(n<sup>2</sup>).

```
concat [[1; 2; 3]; [4; 5; 6]; [7; 8; 9]
```

Is equivalent to:

```
(([] @ [1; 2; 3]) @ [4; 5; 6]) @ [7; 8; 9]
```

This code has to iterate to the end of `[1; 2; 3]` to generate `[1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6]` and *then* has to iterate to the end of `[1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6]` to generate `[1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9]`.

Now imagine our list of lists had a very large number of lists and each was large. The runtime quickly gets out of control.

Instead we can use `::`, which has constant runtime to reduce this to O(n) runtime, as in the following code.

```
let rec concat = function
  | [] -> []
  | []::tl -> concat tl
  | (x::xs)::tl -> x :: concat (xs :: tl)
```

Of course, this is not tail-recursive, so it runs in linear stack space, but fortunately [`tail_mod_cons`](https://v2.ocaml.org/manual/tail_mod_cons.html) gives us an easy fix for this.

```
let[@tail_mod_cons] rec concat = function
  | [] -> []
  | []::tl -> concat tl
  | (x::xs)::tl -> x :: concat (xs :: tl)
```

Comment: Beware that this implementation is potentially quadratic in the size of the final list, because the accumulator (the list concatenated up to the n-th elements) appears on the left hand side of `@`: concat `[[1;2;3];[4;5;6];[7;8;9]]` can be inlined into `(([] @ [1;2;3])@[4;5;6])@[7;8;9])`.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to write `concat` as `fold_left` while avoiding quadractic complexity by switching temporarily to different representation of list

If I have a list `l`, I can easily lift into an append function:

```ml
let to_append l  = fun new_list -> l @ new_list
```

I can also get back a list from an append function with

```ml
let to_list append = append []
```

And since for any list `l`, I have `to_list @@ to_append l` = `l`, this means that the `to_append` is one-to-one: it does not lose any information.

Moreover concatenating two appends functions is exactly function composition

```
let append_concat f g l = f (g l)
```

Since we are not building yet any concrete list, `append_concat` has a constant cost (we are delaying the time complexity to the moment where we will call the append function).

We can use this better behavior of `append_concat` to write a linear `concat'` function that maps a list of lists to an append function:

```
let concat' l =
  List.fold_left 
    (fun append l -> append_concat append (to_append l))
    (to_append [] (* aka Fun.id *))
    l
```

Note that this `concat'` is not yet building a list, it is building a closure which records the list of append functions to call later.

Building `concat` from `concat'` is then a matter of transforming back my append function to a list:

```
let concat l = to_list (concat' l)
```

And it is the call of `to_list` which will have a time complexity equal to the size of the final list.

To check that we got the right complexity, we can test that flattening the following list

```
let test =
  List.init 1_000_000 
   (fun i ->
     List.init 4 (fun k -> k + 4 * i)
   )
(* this is [[0;1;2;3]; [4;5;6;7]; ... [...; 3_999_999]] *)
```

with

```
let flattened = concat test
```

is nearly instant.